# Getting ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 trying to use datanews module

Tags: python, api

I was trying to use the Datanews API but I got a `ValueError`. :-(

Here is my code:

```
import datanews

datanews.api_key = '[API KEY]'

response = datanews.headlines(q='Apple', language=['en'])
articles = response['hits']

num = 0

for num in articles:
    nnum = int(str(num))
    if nnum != 10:
        print(articles[nnum]['title'])
        num = nnum + 1
    else:
        break
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter.py", line 12, in <module>
    nnum = int(str(num))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{\'url\': \'https://www.theapplepost.com/2020/10/22/apple-discontinues-apple-tv-remote-app/\', \'source\': \'theapplepost.com\', \'authors\': [\'The Apple Post\'], \'title\': "Apple discontinues Appl
```

Comment: Which value did you try to convert to which integer?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I tried to convert num into an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 error` is raised when you try to convert a string value that is not formatted as an integer.

To solve this problem, you can use the `float()` method to convert a floating-point number in a string to an integer. Then, you can use `int()` to convert your number to an integer.

If this does not work, make sure that the value of a string does not contain any letters. Strings with letters cannot be converted to an integer unless those letters have a special meaning in Python.

To know correctly >> Debug using `print` statements

```
..............
for num in articles:
    print(num) # This will tell you the truth
    nnum = int(str(num))
..............
```

```
# if you have a list and you want to get index value pair
for i,v in enumerate(yourList)
```

I don't see any `int` in your input:
`'{\'url\': \'https://www.theapplepost.com/2020/10/22/apple-discontinues-apple-tv-remote-app/\', \'source\': \'theapplepost.com\', \'authors\': [\'The Apple Post\'], \'title\': "Apple discontinues Appl`